# prevent back in browser and warning, strict way needed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to prevent the user to switch back to previous pages strictly.  I show you example coding as follows:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">   

/* prevent back  */
window.history.forward();
    function prevent()
    {
window.history.forward(); 
    }


/* warning on unload */
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { var message = 'Are you sure ?'; if (typeof e == 'undefined') { e = window.event; } if (e) { e.returnValue = message; } return message; }


 </script>
 </head>
    <body onload="prevent();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) prevent();" onunload="">
        <!--content here-->
    <a href="in.html">in</a>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The above page have link to another page, if i click back on that second page, it come back to this first page and showing warning and then move to second page;

Second page:

```
<a href="hello.html">hello</a>
```

I added warning script for some reason.

Now, what i need exactly is.  When prevent back working, warning script should not work.

1.When user unload a page, should show warning script
2.when prevent back function unload the page, should not show warning script

Is there any way possible to disable going back from a page in all the way, any strict way? the above coding is not much strict.  it will move forward on getting back.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to 100% restrict user action in a browser. what if the user disables javascript? You need to take action at your backend(server side) for such actions.

Comment: okay, its okay, ...how can we prevent a function when another function triggered

Comment: I've got a decent answer cooking. Up in a sec

Comment: ;-), waiting for to taste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yeah, boi.**

**But seriously, this baby don't got back**

page 1

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>if you go, don't come back</title>
     </head>
     <body>
            <!--content here-->
         <a href="pageofnoreturn.html#noBack">in</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

pageofnoreturn.html

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Stay put, or else</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>welcome to purgatory</h1>
        <script>
            if (location.hash == '#noBack') {
                history.pushState(null, '', '#sit');
                //whatever hashes that suit your project
                window.onhashchange = function() {
                    if (location.hash == '#noBack') {
                        history.pushState(null, '', '#sit');
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd never needed to do that so it was interesting. glad to help!

Comment: Thanks! Todd.  Its very interesting to ask questions more!