# prevent back not working after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I got prevent back coding from here

> [prevent back in browser and warning, strict way needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309561/prevent-back-in-browser-and-warning-strict-way-needed)

it didn't work after a user make refresh, todd, help me regarding this bug.

The code for reference as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Stay put, or else</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>welcome to purgatory</h1>
        <script>
            if (location.hash == '#noBack') {
                history.pushState(null, '', '#sit');
                //whatever hashes that suit your project
                window.onhashchange = function() {
                    if (location.hash == '#noBack') {
                        history.pushState(null, '', '#sit');
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [You can't](http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm), but you can make it harder for the user to hit the back button. I personally would say don't do this, it's terrible from a users standpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Note :*** It's a work around on OP's provided code.]

According to your code when you are navigating to the *purgatory* [Second] page you are concatenating a hashtag '#noBack'. So when on *purgatory* page browser interprets the script if finds a condition when the location has hashtag '#noBack' and change the hashtag to '#sit'.

When you refresh the page this time it has hashtag '#sit' which I handled with another condition which simply change the hashtag back to '#noBack'. So you will be switching between the both if and else-if and won't go to previous page.

```
<script>        
    if (location.hash == '#noBack') {
        history.pushState(null, '', '#sit');
        //whatever hashes that suit your project
        window.onhashchange = function() {
            if (location.hash == '#noBack') {
                history.pushState(null, '', '#sit');
            }
        }
    } else if(location.hash == "#sit"){
        history.pushState(null, '', '#noBack');
        window.onhashchange = function() {
            if (location.hash == '#sit') {
                history.pushState(null, '', '#noBack');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi @ashad...when refreshing the page, the scripts not working

Comment: I've tried it, and it's not going back to the previous page even after I do refresh. Can you have a look again with the script on the answer.

Comment: Thanks Ashad, it working fine even after refresh, and reload the url